# Chrome web browser allow persistent storage

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-chrome-extension, user-agent, ripple

Running Ripple emulator (phonegap) on Ubuntu Linux. In my app (jquery mobile) I want to create a file (using persistent storage), problem is that the allowed storage quota is 0 for persistent storage and 2gb for temporary storage.

So this works :

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {...});
```

but if i change to `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY` then `grantedBytes == 0`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you seeing this issue only in Ripple?  Or do you also see the same behavior when you run your code in the browser (with Ripple disabled)?  If this is a ripple-only issue, I'd suggest filing a bug here: https://github.com/blackberry/Ripple-UI/issues

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem.

Persistent storage requires user's permission in Chrome.
You can request it by:

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024 /* 5MB */, function(grantedBytes) {
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
}, function(e) {
  console.log('Error', e);
});
```

I found that solution at [blackberry support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/More-details-about-FileSystem-API-support-in-Ripple-Emulator-v0/td-p/1920345) and at least for me it worked.